# Filtering Empty DataGridView through TextBox (C#, WinForms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a dataGridView to which I've loaded the data from the little arrow at the top-right corner. And my plan is to use a `textbox_TextChanged` event to filter it. Everywhere I searched, they entered the table data through code.

My code so far looks like this:

```
public frmCompletedReservations()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CompletedReservations_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'completedReservationsDataSet.CompletedReservations' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.completedReservationsTableAdapter.Fill(this.completedReservationsDataSet.CompletedReservations);
    }

    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView reserv = new DataView(completedReservationsDataSet);
        reserv.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
        dgvCompletedReserv.DataSource = reserv;
    }
```

At `new DataView(completedReservationsDataSet);` it gives me an error.

**What does this mean**, **what am I doing wrong** and **how should I correct it**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter in DataView's constructor must be an object type of [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Data_DataView__ctor_System_Data_DataTable_).

So you need to modify it like this.

```
DataView reserv = new DataView(completedReservationsDataSet.CompletedReservations);
```